# How to get id from list of object using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have api call on $on i got the Json response that is attached with the question. i was able to display fileName in the `li` , Now i have delete function when user click on remove icon i am calling function and trying to get `rskAsesAprvAtchKy` key so i can post the key to backend to delete this file.

It is coming undefined i am not sure what i am missing any help will be appreciated..

main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
            <li ng - repeat="file in attachedDoc">{{file . fileName}}
                <a href="" ng - click="deleteFile()">
                    <span class="glyph_remove"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

factory.js

```
$scope.$on('addEditAttest', function (s, attestorObj) {
    $scope.attestorObj = attestorObj;
    attestorFactory.getAttachedDocument($scope.attestorObj.riskAssessmentRoleAsgnKey)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.attachedDoc = response.data;
        });
});

$scope.deleteFile = function () {
    var fileKey;
    $scope.attachedDoc.rskAsesAprvAtchKy = fileKey;
    console.log("deleted", fileKey);
}
```

JSON.JS

```
[{
    "rskAsesAprvAtchKy": 1001,
    "fileName": "Doc 1",
    "rskAsesRoleAsgnKy": 1277
}]
```

Comment: Hi, you defined the fileKey var, and it is undefined,, you probably need to do vice verse something like this... `fileKey = $scope.attachedDoc.id` right?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the key as parameter for the `ng-click` method:

**At the view**

```
<li ng-repeat="file in attachedDoc">{{file.fileName}}
     <a href="" ng-click="deleteFile(file.rskAsesAprvAtchKy, $index)"> //Key from the file
        <span class="glyph_remove">
        </span>
     </a>
</li>
```

**Change the delete method**

```
$scope.deleteFile = function(fileKey, fileIndex){
   /*Delete the file*/
   $scope.attachedDoc.splice(fileIndex, 1); //remove the file at position fileIndex 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Passing the $index from the ng-repeat and using [Array.splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) will do the job. See above.

Comment: Thanks it worked i got the id by passing parameter, once i delete the file how can i remove item from list view ?